# Calculate vector position

Tags: vector-spaces, circles, 3d, average

I'm trying to calculate & move vertices to their average "radius" and form a circle from these new positions.

Example: I have 8 vertices selected, I have a little script in Maya that will iterate through each point, find the distance from the center of the selection to the current point in the loop. It saves these values and creates an "average distance from the center" value.

[image]

- Black = Each vertex position (X,Y,Z)
- Red = Distance between center and vertex
- Blue = Average of ALL verts from the Centerpoint (X,Y,Z) & Vertex (X,Y,Z) = integerXYZ (blue is the same distance)
- Green is the position I'm trying to find in (XYZ)

I can't figure out how to calculate the (X,Y,Z) coordinates of the green dot!

I have calculated this information with: (up to the position of the green points):

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import math
sel = cmds.ls(sl=1, fl=1)
averageDistance = 0
cmds.setToolTo('Move')
oldCoordArray = []
oldDistanceArray = []
newXPos = 0
cs = cmds.manipMoveContext("Move", q=1, p=1)
for i in range(0, len(sel), 1):
    vts = cmds.xform(sel[i],q=1,ws=1,t=1)
    print vts
    x = round(float(cs[0]),2) - round(float(vts[0]),2)
    y = round(float(cs[1]),2) - round(float(vts[1]),2)
    z = round(float(cs[2]),2) - round(float(vts[2]),2)
    distanceFromCenter = math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z))
    oldCoordArray += [(round(float(vts[0]),2),round(float(vts[1]),2),round(float(vts[2]),2))]
    oldDistanceArray += [(distanceFromCenter)]
    averageDistance += distanceFromCenter    
    if (i == len(sel) -1):
        averageDistance /= len(sel)
        print 'average Distance: %s' %averageDistance
        for i in range(0, len(sel), 1):
            #Calculate percentage difference between distances
            t = oldDistanceArray[i] * 100 / averageDistance
            percDiff = (t / 100) * oldCoordArray[i][0]
            newXPos -= (oldCoordArray[i][0] / percDiff) * 100
```

(original image [here](http://www.shannonhochkins.com/_images/51356069965f59b00b00011f))

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I can't calculate the X,Y,Z coordinates of the green dot basically!

Comment: Oh crap. This is 3D, and I did 2D in an earlier answer I'll remove right after this comment. For 3D, you should consider using polar coordinates. If 2D is of any help, let me know, and I'll undelete my 2D answer that is fully written.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you have looped through the eight points $(X_i,Y_i,Z_i)$and averaged the $X,Y,Z$ coordinates to find the red coordinates, call them $(X_c,Y_c,Z_c)$  The distance of each point from the center is $d_i=\sqrt{(X_i-X_c)^2+(Y_i-Y_c)^2+(Z_i-Z_c)^2}$.  If you just average all the $d_i$ the blue segments will extend past the nearer points.  It is not clear to me how you choose the blue length $b$.  But however you do it, the coordinates of the green points $g_i=\left(\frac b{d_i}(X_i-X_c)+X_c,\frac b{d_i}(Y_i-Y_c)+Y_c,\frac b{d_i}(Z_i-Z_c)+Z_c\right)$

Comment: How would this return 3 coordinates? (X,Y,Z) I'm not quite following sorry

Comment: If it helps, I have updated my question with my current python code.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins:  there are three coordinates shown.  The $X$ one is $\frac b{d_i}(X_i-X_c)+X_c$

Comment: Oh i didn't even notice the "," You're not able to take a quick look at my python code and explain how I might implement it would you?

Comment: is the 'b' the "blue" distance??

Comment: @ShannonHochkins:  yes,$b$ is the blue distance.  From your code, it looks like it is the average of the $d_i$, which means the blue segment will extend past some of the points-maybe that is OK.  I don't know why you round to 2 places so often-usually you calculate without rounding and only round to display.  Your oldDistanceArray is my $d_i$ then I think we are doing the same thing, scaling the difference in coordinates to get the desired length.  I don't understand going through percentage, either.

Comment: The idea behind the percentage part was if I found the percentage difference between the old distance from the center to the oldValues, that I could calculate the percentage difference of that percentage from the old translate values giving me the green values.

So using my current code, would my new expression just for GX be:
`gX = (averageDistance / distanceFromCenter * (vts[0] - cs[0]) + cs[0])`

Comment: @ShannonHochkins:  I haven't checked the variables, but that looks like what I suggested.

Comment: If you find the time are you able to quickly check the variables? I just want to double check :)

Comment: @ShannonHochkins: cs should be the average of all the points and vts should be each point, but it isn't clear to me where they come from.

Comment: Hi @RossMillikan ,  I can't seem to log into this account that I was using to create this post, I have no idea why, but if you wouldn't mind taking a look at this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321384/calculating-new-vector-positions